# I defined both of my functions but it doesn't plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hi guys im trying to plot these two functions x(x2) vs y(x2). x(x2) being equal to log10(x_2) and y(x_2) being equal to gam(x2) which was then equal also equal to (gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * math.log10(1+628.14*55.556*x_2)). It seems like the code for y(x_2) works fine but i can't seem to get the code for x(x_2) to work. When it does plot it should look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St4r9.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import pylab

%matplotlib inline


gam0 = 72.8
temp = 293.15

#x = range(0, 10000)
#x_2= range(0, 10000)

def gam(x_2):
    returns = []
    for x_i in x_2:
        returns.append(gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * math.log10(1+628.14*55.556*x_i))
    return returns
def x(x_2):
    returns = math.log10(x_2)
    x()
 



plt.plot(gam(x_2), x(x_2))

plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')
plt.show()
```

These are the errors im getting

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ac6002d962a0> in <module>
    25 
    26 
---> 27 plt.plot(gam(x_2), x(x_2))
    28 
    29 plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')

<ipython-input-13-ac6002d962a0> in x(x_2)
    19     return returns
    20 def x(x_2):
---> 21     returns = numpy.log10(x_2)
    22 
    23     return returns
```

Comment: The indentation in your code seems wrong. Can you please check and match it to your actual code to avoid any confusion?

Comment: In your definition of function `x(x_2)`, you are never returning anything. You probably forgot the line `return returns`.

Comment: So i fixed the indentation and added `return returns` but i still got errors

Comment: Then you should add what those errors are. Otherwise people will have to guess.

Comment: lol Yeah im about too

Comment: Since you have `import numpy as np`, it needs to be `np.log10(x_2)`

Comment: yeah i realized that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a number of issues with your code:

1. Your function `x(x_2)` is not return anything. Instead it keeps calling itself recursively.
2. You are calling `math.log10`, which only acts on a single number, not an array. You can either wrap that in a loop, or call the `numpy` version.
3. In your function `gam(x_2)` you are using `log10`, but `log` is needed.
4. Your plot range is of, you need much smaller values on the x-axis.
   I added two variants, because the spacing of the grid points is different on the linear and logarithmic scales. Also, with `np.linspace()` you can specify the number of grid points, instead of the step size. (For details see https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Here is the overall code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

gam0 = 72.8
temp = 293.15

x_2 = np.linspace(1e-7, 1e-1, 1000)     # evenly spaced on linear scale
x_2 = 10**np.linspace(-7, -1, 1000)     # evenly spaced on logarithmic scale


def gam(x_2):
    return gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * np.log(1+628.14*55.556*x_2)

def x(x_2):
    return np.log10(x_2)
 
plt.plot(x(x_2), gam(x_2))
plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')
```

It is also possible, to let matplotlib deal with the log scale on the x-axis:

```
plt.plot(x_2, gam(x_2))    
plt.xlabel('x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')    
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
```

Comment: So it plotted but it gave me a straight line and the warning:
               
  C:\Users\Megas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:21: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10

Comment: If you use `x_2= range(0, 10000)`, then you are trying to calculate log(0), which is not defined. You have to exclude that point from your plot.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I just need to figure out why i'm getting a straight line and not a  curve

Comment: @MegasXLR I think your range for `x_2` is wrong. It should go from 1E-6.5 to 1E-1.5, not from 0 to 1E5.

Comment: Yeah  is changed it to that but im not sure if i wrote it correctly this is how i wrote it.   `x_2 in np.arange(10**-6.5, 10**-1.5)`

Comment: The default step size is 1, so this will give you a single number only. See https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: @MegasXLR I updated the answer. This code should reproduce the plot as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im curious why you got rid of the loop? and how np.linspace works? I'm sorry if asking to many questions. I'm a beginner and started taking classes online for coding

Comment: `linspace` is very similar to `arange`, for details and examples check the linked Numpy documentation. Replacing the for loop is optional, but faster and easier to read. Numpy automatically takes care of the loop. If your problems are solved, please upvote and accept the answer.